# PHP Only Returning One Value from DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following code:

```
$getrand = "SELECT DISTINCT Name from Events Order BY Rand() Limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$getrand);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo "<div class = 'container'>Name: $data[0]</br>";
$gettags = "SELECT Tag From Events where Name = '$data[0]'";
$tagresult = mysqli_query($con, $gettags);
$tagdata = mysqli_fetch_array($tagresult);
echo "$tagdata[0], $tagdata[1]";
```

However it is only returning one value from `tagdata`. My database looks like:

### ID | Name | Tag

And there can be multiple tags for one name (ie multiple rows of tags per name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your recordset like this ...

```
$getrand = "SELECT DISTINCT Name from Events Order BY Rand() Limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$getrand);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo "<div class = 'container'>Name: $data[0]</br>";
$gettags = "SELECT Tag From Events where Name = '$data[0]'";
$tagresult = mysqli_query($con, $gettags);

while($tagdata = mysqli_fetch_array($tagresult)) // a while loop has been used here
{
echo $tagdata['Tag'];// 'tag' your column name (change it as per your requirement)
}
```